# Merge function in R with certain columns and all entries wether matched or unmatched from two data frames

Tags: r, package

Now i am trying to change column names for each file instead of column number 2 which I am designating as "v1" on the basis of which I have to merge. and storing column name of column number 4 in cn variable as i want that column to be pasted from each file into single file.When I am using the following code:

```
a=scan("names of sample", what=character())
g=5
q=6
p=1
m=3
n=4
for(id in a)
{
input=sprintf("%s%s%s","path//", id, "_chr1_cover_meth.txt")
input_file1=read.delim(input,stringsAsFactors=F, header=F)
ccn=colnames(input_file1)[2]=paste0("v1")
colnames(input_file1)[1]=paste0("S",p)
colnames(input_file1)[3]=paste0("S",m)
cn=colnames(input_file1)[4]=paste0("S",n)
colnames(input_file1)[5:6]=paste0("S",g:q)
file<- merge(x=file,y=input_file1[,c(ccn,cn)] , by="v1", all=T)
g=g+6
q=q+6
p=p+1
m=m+6
n=n+6
}
```

I am getting errors:
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame
Error in `[.data.frame`(input_file1, , c(ccn, cn)) : 
  undefined columns selected
What should I do now??/

I have 100 files that I want to merge by a common column. I want to have all the records(rows) wether matching or not to be in the resultant file and I also only certain column to be merged in the answer file as follow.

file1:

```
       v1      v2    v346 v446 v546 v466  
330496 chr1 3005150 3005150    0    0    2  
330497 chr1 3005206 3005206    0    0    1  
330498 chr1 3010805 3010805    0    0    1  
330499 chr1 3010875 3010875    0    0    1  
330500 chr1 3010895 3010895    0    0    1  
330501 chr1 3011159 3011159  100    1    0
```

file2:

```
         v0      v2     v36 v46 v56 v66
379488 chr1 3005010 3005010 100   1   0
379489 chr1 3005056 3005056 100   1   0
379490 chr1 3031241 3031241 100   1   0
379491 chr1 3031268 3031268 100   1   0
379492 chr1 3031275 3031275 100   1   0
379493 chr1 3086797 3086797   0   0   1
```

I want to merge in a way as I will get all the records from both the file wether matching or not.

desired Output is:

```
                                      v46(file2)
3005010 NA        NA    NA   NA  NA  100
3005056 NA        NA    NA   NA  NA  100
3005150 chr1 3005150    0    0    2   NA
```

Actually, I aim to get all the rows from all the files in a single file at the end.
Also I want to know whether it will work in R or not? As for the 2 files it is running efficiently but I don't know for 100 files what will happen and the size of the file is 48.5 MB each.

Comment: You are only extracting column v46 from t2 so R cannot match on column v2

Comment: Thanks alot.I want to know that will it work on 100 files or not and in 100 files how can I change the colnames/(assign unique colnames)

Comment: You could easily make a loop that would merge file2 with file1 and then file3 with file1+2. It might be slow. Unique column names could be assigned afterwards (or before).  There will be faster solutions with data.table::merge() but I haven't used this.

Comment: thanks. but how can I assign unique columns to every file evry time?

Comment: It's not at all clear why you are stuck. Is the problem you don't know how to edit column names? Is the problem you don't know how to generate unique names? Is it both? Do you have a vector of file names already? Do you actually want parentheses in your column names (generally this is considered bad practice)?

Comment: Actually I dont know how to assign unique names every time to a new file to be merged.I have 100 file so i will make aloop and in that case if i assign v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6 to 1st file and v10,v2,v33,v44,v55,v66 to other file merge by using the function o=merge(x = file1, y = file22[ , c("v2","v44")], by = "v2", all=TRUE) then for the 3rd file i will again assign v10,v2,v33,v44,v55,v66 to the column names. ISnt it give any error because of the same names of column in the merged file1+2 and then in file3(name of col v44 will be same)

Comment: following code to merg files a=scan("Sample_names.txt", what=character())
for(id in a)
{input=sprintf("%s%s%s","path/", id, "_chr1_cover_meth.txt")
input_file1=read.delim(input,stringsAsFactors=F, header=F)
colnames(input_file1)=c("v0","v2","v3","v4","v5","v6")
p <- merge(x=p,y=input_file1, by="v2", all=T)
} It gave me 50 warnings 50: In merge.data.frame(x, input_file1, by = "v2", all = T) :
  column names ‘v0.x’, ‘v0.y’, ‘v3.x’, ‘v4.x’, ‘v5.x’, ‘v6.x’, ‘v0.x’, ‘v3.y’, ‘v4.y’, ‘v5.y’, ‘v6.y’, ‘v0.y’, ‘v3.x’, ‘v4.x’, ‘v5.x’, ‘v6.x’, ‘v0.x’, ‘v3.y’, ‘v4.y’, ‘v5.y’, ‘v6.y’,, ’, ‘ [... truncated]

Comment: above code gave me  all the columns from each file while from each file I need only column no.2 and column number 4  for all the records common or uncommon and nothing else.Please if any one could guide me.